# Color in bash prompt messes up git output

Tags: bash, shell, git, bashrc

I changed my .bashrc to include `export PS1="\033[1;33m\u@\h: \w>\033[0m"` so that my shell prompt would be colored, but it seems the `\033` messes up git output (log and diff, at least). I see something like: `ESC[33mcommit long-commit-number ESC[m`.

I also tried `\e[` instead of `\033[`, but I still see the `ESC[33m`. Is there a way to avoid this yet keep the color for my shell prompt?

Comment: If you `export PS1` from bash prompt (not within `.bashrc`), do you still get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your prompt setting is incorrect, but not related at all to the git problem.

To make line editing work (i.e. to know where the cursor is after the prompt's printed), bash needs to know exactly how wide the prompt is. It cannot recognize every possible terminal-specific escape sequence out there, so it needs to be told explicitly that certain parts of the prompt are invisible; they have to be surrounded by `\[` and `\]` codes. For example:

```
PS1="\[\033[1;33m\]\u@\h: \w>\[\033[m\]"
```

Without doing this, typing a command longer than one line will very often result in the second line overwriting the first one, and other glitches.

However, none of this affects git. The reason `git log` prints a `ESC[33m` is because *git itself* wants that line to be shown in yellow – it always does so when the colour option, `color.ui`, is enabled. The reason you *see* the word "ESC" instead of yellow is because your $PAGER doesn't recognize the sequence; it thinks you're reading a file with binary data (as opposed to human-readable text).

If you're using the default `less` pager as $PAGER, **it could be that you added some custom options to the `$LESS` variable** and forgot the one that allows colors, `-R`. Normally git sets `$LESS` internally when running a pager, but if you set that variable yourself git won't touch it and you have to add `-R` to it:

```
export LESS="R"

export LESS="e M q R F X z -3"
```

...or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you! Added `export LESS="R"` and it seems to have fixed it. Not sure what set $LESS or where it's set, though I do see a `.lesshst` file in my directory. I still see a couple `^M` characters here and there in the git diff, but could just be characters in my files or something.

Comment: `.lesshst` doesn't keep any settings; it keeps the _history_ of what text you searched in files (using the `/` or `?` keys) when reading them through `less`.

Comment: As for the `^M`, it's shown by `git diff`, to alert you that the line has a CR character (carriage return) in it – in other words, that it uses Windows 'CR LF' line-endings instead of Unix 'LF' ones. `^M` comes from the fact that the CR byte is the same as the "M" byte with the three highest bits reset; it's a common syntax to show the normally-invisible "control" characters.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the `.lesshst` file and it wasn't very helpful, nor did I remember doing those things. There's probably another program that uses it like git.

Thanks for clearing up the `^M`.

Comment: There are many; for example, `man`.